# C Kernel Module - Get uuid of block device by path

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

how can I get the uuid of a block device in the linux kernel?
uuid should be like blkid/dumpe2fs

except:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="33b88f94-3688-408a-b368-7c5ebf8543cb" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="aa2030fb-01"
```

I tried to climb inside the struct block_device

Comment: Have you checked _block/bdev.c_ sources?